# Как удалить привязки DataGridViewComboBoxCell из dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать сброс `dataGridView1` в начальное состояние, т. е удалить все строки и вставить новые изначальные.

Во время вставки изначальных строк ошибка:

> ячейки с `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` уже принадлежат сетке.

Как очистить привязки `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` в `dataGridView` ?

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
//  dataGridView1.DataMember=null;
dataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear();
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Cells.Clear();           
long totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
```

Заполнение сетки dataGridView1:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell CB1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, "Обозначение ЛЭП");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, "для кабелей напряжением, кВ");
CB1.Items.AddRange("0.5", "3", "6");
dataGridView1[5, 7] = CB1;
CB1.Value = "0.5";

dataGridView1[5, 7] = CB1;//строка с ошибкой
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: Указанная ячейка уже принадлежит к
>   сетке. Выполнение операции невозможно. в
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCollection.set_ltem(lnt32 index,
>   DataGridViewCell value) в
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_ltem(lnt32 columnindex, Int32
>   rowindex, DataGridViewCell value)

Comment: Как данные были занесены в грид изначально?

Comment: как скинуть исходник?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вы не используете привязку данных (data binding). Вы работаете напрямую со строками и ячейками датагрида.

Соответственно, очищать нужно именно строки:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

Всё, больше ничего не нужно.

---

Если бы использовалась привязка:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = someCollection;
```

тогда очистка производилась бы так:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

Comment: Ошибка System.InvalidOperationException: Указанная ячейка уже принадлежит к сетке.

Answer (score 0):

```
  dataGridView1[5, 7] = CB1;

    CB1.Value = "0.5";
```

Тут уже недопустимое значение вылетает. 
(Должен быть типа
ObjectCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable)

```
dataGridView1[5, 7] = CB1;
```

Тут повторно пытаетесь присвоить ссылку на тот же объект.
Можно присвоить на НОВУЮ ячейку:

```
new DataGridViewComboBoxCell()...
```

или работать с тем же списком CB1.Items,
значит, чтоб его перезаписать: его и надо очистить сперва:

```
CB1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: Пробую на Visual Studio 2019 Preview -ни чего не получается. На SharpDevelop 5.1 - всё работает без танцев с бубном!